# In react, is it better to pass props to child components or using useSelector in child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

For example I have 3 components, here is the nest relationship

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
    </c>
  </b>
</a>
```

should I create useSelector in compontn a? and pass props to c. or should I just useSelector in c? what will be the main difference?

Comment: passing the prop would be good if the nesting is for level3 only as any state change in child would trigger parent to re-render. Also, it depend on your use-case.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you need the the some data from the `useSelector()` in `Component a`, you can choose to remove it from `Component a` and create it in the `Component c`. Or you can have them in both `Component a` and `Component c`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).